# How to display AJAX & form content with jQuery in overlays (similar to recreating Lightview displays)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, overlay

We would like to display a simple checkout flow all within jQuery overlays, but we don't know how to smoothly swap out the content when the user clicks to the next page of the flow. Using an iFrame as the content for the overlay seems to fail, because the overlay code we are using doesn't seem to support iFrames.

The flow is very simple and contains three pages. Page one is a form with one field. Page two is a login screen. Page three is a confirmation screen.

Ideally, the overlay will scale to fit the content in a smooth fashion. It would operate similar to Lightview for AJAX & Forms. (Click "Ajax & Forms" in the Lightview demo section to see what I mean: http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/.)

1) Is there a free plugin to deliver this experience? Lightview is fairly expensive for a plugin and offers a superset of functionality.

2) If no free plugin exists, what's the best approach for building this in jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We spent a lot of time researching alternatives.

The best one for us was [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/). There were a few reasons, not the least of which is the fact the plugin remains under active development.

We looked at [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/), [Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/), [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), and a host of other options.

If you want to hear our reasons, please comment below. Otherwise, we'll assume no one cares. :)

Comment: I would be interested in knowing your reasons.